# Generating solid grid graph examples

Tags: c++, graph, grid, generator, testcase

Do you have any idea about How we can make a code that generates random solid grid graph examples?

Definition of solid grid graph (from:http://www.graphclasses.org/classes/gc_1058.html):

> A graph is a solid grid graph iff it is a grid graph that can be
>   embedded in the plane such that the vertices lie on integer
>   coordinates, the edges have unit length and all interior faces have
>   unit area. (The first two conditions hold for every grid graph, the
>   third says that the embedding contains no `holes'.)

Comment: what tools are you using for this?

Comment: I don't use any tool, I want to code it. I am using c++ for this project.